# Getting error while installing rexray/ebs

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I was trying to install rexray/ebs plugin the installation was successful,
But after the installation there was some error showing up.

**Docker Version**

```
Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.1
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
```

---

```
# docker plugin install rexray/ebs EBS_ACCESSKEY=my_access_key  EBS_SECRETKEY=my_secret_key
```

---

```
Plugin "rexray/ebs" is requesting the following privileges:
 - network: [host]
 - mount: [/dev]
 - allow-all-devices: [true]
 - capabilities: [CAP_SYS_ADMIN]
Do you grant the above permissions? [y/N] y
latest: Pulling from rexray/ebs
713b84867e46: Download complete 
Digest: sha256:bbe1cfc5241d765c735e1d80fd790a0fc50e2e7064239255c4b61397a16c3355
Status: Downloaded newer image for rexray/ebs:latest
Error response from daemon: dial unix /run/docker/plugins/9f30e9e6697e8b4ca35750d318df1e463b7776632d0abb4bbf920bcdc504d131/rexray.sock: connect: no such file or directory
```

---

> Note

My Accesskey and Screcetkey are working finely I have checked it alreay.

Comment: Did you manage to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Just reinstall docker by using flowing command. This will help you.

> sudo apt install -y docker.io
>
> sudo usermod -aG docker $user
>
> shutdown -r now

then try same.